# Count Leaf Nodes In a Generic Tree (Recursively)

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, tree, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make a C++ program to count the number of Leaf Nodes in a generic tree using a Recurisve approach.

here is my code:

```
int countLeafNodes(TreeNode<int> *root)
{
    if (root = NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int total = 0;
    if (root->children.size() == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < root->children.size(); i++)
    {
        total += countLeafNodes(root->children[i]);
    }
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    TreeNode<int> *root = takeInputLevelWise();
    cout << "Total Leaf Nodes = " << countLeafNodes(root) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't get any output on my editor (vs code) so I tested it on an online judge and it was giving `SIGSEGV` error. I know we get that error for an Invalid memory reference but I don't understand where in my code I am doing that mistake. Please someone tell me what's wrong with the code and why it is not working.

here is the complete code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class TreeNode
{
public:
    T data;
    vector<TreeNode<T> *> children;

    TreeNode(T data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
    ~TreeNode()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
        {
            delete children[i];
        }
    }
};

TreeNode<int> *takeInputLevelWise()
{
    int rootData;
    cout << "Enter Root Data" << endl;
    cin >> rootData;
    TreeNode<int> *root = new TreeNode<int>(rootData);

    queue<TreeNode<int> *> pendingNode;
    pendingNode.push(root);
    while (!pendingNode.empty())
    {
        TreeNode<int> *front = pendingNode.front();
        pendingNode.pop();
        int numChild;
        cout << "Enter number of children of " << front->data << endl;
        cin >> numChild;
        for (int i = 0; i < numChild; i++)
        {
            int childData;
            cout << "Enter " << i << "th child of " << front->data << endl;
            cin >> childData;
            TreeNode<int> *child = new TreeNode<int>(childData);
            front->children.push_back(child);
            pendingNode.push(child);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int countLeafNodes(TreeNode<int> *root)
{
    if (root = NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int total = 0;
    if (root->children.size() == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < root->children.size(); i++)
    {
        total += countLeafNodes(root->children[i]);
    }
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    TreeNode<int> *root = takeInputLevelWise();
    cout << "Total Leaf Nodes = " << countLeafNodes(root) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure there is no problem with the TreeNode class or takeInputLevelWise() function as I have used the same code in many other questions to generate the tree. The problem must be in the countLeafNodes() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in your `countLeafNodes` function.

```cpp
if (root = NULL)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Hope you find the error.

Comment: Thanks a ton , I am laughing after seeing the mistake I had made lol.